# Retrieving list items and displaying them

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, caml

I have a collection of list items retrieved via CAML query. I have only set the query to retrieve only the three lates items.

From the collection of items I then want to retrive these three items by index and output them to placeholders, however this is currently not working. Is there anything that I have missed?

CAML query:

```
string displayOnHomePage = "True";

SPQuery queryNewsItems = new SPQuery();

queryNewsItems.Query = @"<Where>" +
                        "<Neq>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='DisplayOnHomePage'/>" +
                        "<Value Type='Boolean'>" + displayOnHomePage +
                        "</Value>" +
                        "</Neq>" +
                        "</Where>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='ImageCreateDate' Ascending ='False'/>" +
                        "</OrderBy>";

queryNewsItems.RowLimit = 3;
SPListItemCollection newsItemsCollection = newsItems.GetItems(queryNewsItems);
```

Getting the first list item and attempting to display them on the page using a place holder:

```
string newsHeadlineItem1 = newsItemsCollection[0]["NewsHeadline"].ToString();
string newsDescriptionItem1 = newsItemsCollection[0]["NewsDescription"].ToString();

plhNewsHeadlineItem1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(newsHeadlineItem1));
plhNewsDescriptionItem1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(newsDescriptionItem1));
```

Getting the second list item and attempting to display them on the page using a place holder:

```
string newsHeadlineItem2 = newsItemsCollection[1]["NewsHeadline"].ToString();
string newsDescriptionItem2 = newsItemsCollection[1]["NewsDescription"].ToString();

plhNewsHeadlineItem2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(newsHeadlineItem2));
plhNewsDescriptionItem2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(newsDescriptionItem2));
```

The reson I am not using a foreach loop to loop through the collection of items is because I want to controll to which placeholder they are displayed on e.g.

The first item will be output to the plhNewsHeadlineItem1 and plhNewsDescriptionItem1 placeholders.

The second item will be output to the plhNewsHeadlineItem2 and plhNewsDescriptionItem2 placeholders.

And similarly for the thrid item will be output to the plhNewsHeadlineItem3 plhNewsDescriptionItem3 placeholders.

Is this the correct approach to access and display the the three list items from the collection of items retrieved by the CAML query?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually working, the issue was the library/list I was using (original created from a list template)for some reason the fields were not being picked up. I Deleted the library/list and re-created it and it is all woring as expected.